# Why do we need to specify a port number while using HTTP protocol?

Tags: http, networking, web, ip, port

Why do we need to specify a port number with an IP address even if we are using HTTP protocol? For example - `http://xyz:8080...` - what does this even mean? We already know that while using HTTP the request will be served at port 80, so why do we specify a port explicitly?

Comment: You don"t, unless it isn't 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default port for HTTP is 80 and HTTPS is 443 but port numbers range from 0 to 65535. Most web servers listen on the default port so it's simpler to refer to the URL without the port. For example, `https://www.cnn.com/` refers to the same resource as `https://www.cnn.com:443/` since port 443 is the default port.

> If an HTTP/HTTPS service is other than the default port then the port must be specified in the URL.

The URL is defined by [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) with this simplified syntax which includes the port:

```
<scheme>://<host>:<port>/<url-path>
```

So for example, the URL `http://xyz:8080/...` refers to a host machine name or IP address listening to port 8080 with HTTP as the protocol. The HTTP (or web) server at that address then resolves the *url-path* to the particular service or file.

The port is optional when it is the default port for the given scheme or protocol (e.g., HTTP=80).

A given machine can host multiple different products with HTTP services on different ports. For example, Apache web server is listening to port 80 on a given server while Apache Tomcat is listening to port 8080 on the same machine. Various database and messaging products typically have HTTP services on different ports.

**The port is part of the address from which a client can reference a specific service**.

Comment: Why does the aforementioned RFC 1738 contain no section on HTTPS, but only 3.3 HTTP? 
I'm wondering what's the difference between `http://xyz:8080/...` and `https://xyz:8080/...`, and whether `https://xyz:8080/...` can be explained in a similar way, where 8080 overwrites default port 443

Comment: RFC-1738 provides generic URL syntax. [RFC-7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) has details on HTTPS. If port is specified in a URL then it is used regardless of the default port for that protocol.

Answer (score 2):

A port is like a "channel" in a way... If you have to access different functions of the same website, you use different ports. HTTP is port 80, HTTPS is 443, SSH is 22, and so on.