# How to hide port number in a url

Tags: java, apache, url, rhel, port-number

I have run an application on a cloud server..i am accessing the url https://xx.xx.xx.xx:5004/double/request with a public Ip. Can it be possible to access the url https://xx.xx.xx.xx/double/request(Without port number)

Comment: Since http defaults to port 80 and https to 443, you can probably set up connectors in your server config to redirect to that desired port, i.e. 5004.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port) should work.

Comment: By default ig goes to either 80 or 443. Don't know how much access you have, but you could probably can have a apache as proxy server? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Answer (score 2):

Default port for **HTTPS** is 443. So you can just **change your port to 443** and will be able to use *https://xx.xx.xx.xx/double/request*

More infos about port number : See this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888270/why-do-we-need-to-specify-a-port-number-while-using-http-protocol).

Comment: The linked Q&A is good information but I don't think it answers the OP's question within context.

Comment: Better like this ?

Comment: Mmh. OP has tagged their question java and apache. Assuming Tomat, there are specific recipies for configuring your server to direct traffic based on port. Your answer doesn't cover that, and neither does it seem to indicate how to direct http/s traffic to a specific port.

Answer (score 0):

What about using of services that short url: e.g. `tiny.ly`?

Comment: Its a jar file i am running on rhel  server

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to access **the "https" url of "5004" port number** without **"5004"**.

So, to access **the "https" url of your application** without **port number**, you need to change **"5004" port number of the "https" url of your application** to **"443" port number** because **"443" port number** is default to **"https"**.

In addition, **"80" port number** is default to **"http"**.