# Flask application with Nginx & Gunicorn using Custom Domain Name for IP:Port

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, firewall

I have deployed a Flask application on Ubuntu with Gunicorn & Nginx serving requests

Nginx conf:

```
server {
server_name server_name domain_name;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/darshit/myproject/myproject.sock;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/fullchain.pem; # managed by 
Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
if ($host = domain_name) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name server_name domain_name;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Now, the application accepts request on port 443 for httos. The private ip has been mapped to public ip and port 443 of the server has been mapped to serve requests on port 9991.
Inorder to access the application over the internet, the user has to hit: https://domain_name:9991

I want the application to serve requests without mentioning the port name i.e on https://domain_name

What changes to be made? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide port number in a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422403/how-to-hide-port-number-in-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your gunicorn is listening on port 9991, you need to configure nginx to upstream requests to it.

Here's how you do it:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location /static  {
    alias /path/to/static/folder/of/application;
    }

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:9991;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

Points to note:

The first block of code listens to on port 80 for any connection and simply does a permanent redirect to port 443. This is needed so that if your user types in http://example.com it should redirect to https://example.com

Now, the second block listens on port 443 for secure connections with the keys configured below that and essentially upstreams the request to port 9991 where your gunicorn is running.

**Pro-tip:** I've added an additional block of `location /static` which basically matches any request with `/static` in it and serves it from your application's static folder. The static files like images, stylesheets, etc should not be served by your application server, it should ideally be served by a web server like nginx.